# React Leaflet how to set min/max Zoom for scrollwheel using state variables?

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I 'm working with a React Leaflet map that uses state variables to set properties of the map. I tried the following in my code to allow for a min and max zoom when someone uses the scrollwheel. Currently it still does not enable the min and max zoom. Any suggestions on why it's not working? Thank you!

```
export default function Home () {
  //creating use state variables
  const [center, setCenter] = useState([43.88, -72.7317])
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(8)
const [minZoom, setMinZoom] = useState(5)
const [maxZoom, setMaxZoom] = useState(15)
  const [featuredDisplay, setFeaturedDisplay] = useState(true)
  const [countyStoryDisplay, setCountyStoryDisplay] = useState(false)
  const [selectedCounty, setSelectedCounty] = useState('')
  const [shuffledIndex, setShuffledIndex] = useState(0)
  const [impact, setImpact] = useState('')
  const [navCountySelect, setNavCountySelect] = useState('')
  const [mobileView, setMobileView] = useState(false)
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)

  //creating a material ui style for maroon text
  const MaroonTextTypography = withStyles({
    root: {
      color: '#5a203c'
    }
  })(Typography)

  //useEffect to set the mobile view for navigation based on the window width
  useEffect(() => {
    const setResponsiveness = () => {
      return window.innerWidth < 900
        ? setMobileView(true)
        : setMobileView(false)
    }

    setResponsiveness()
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => setResponsiveness())

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', () => setResponsiveness())
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>

//map component
 <Map
            navCountySelect={navCountySelect}
            isSelected={isSelected}
            setIsSelected={setIsSelected}
            center={center}
            setCenter={setCenter}
            zoom={zoom}
            setZoom={setZoom}
            setMinZoom={setMinZoom}
            setMaxZoom={setMaxZoom}
            setFeaturedDisplay={setFeaturedDisplay}
            setSelectedCounty={setSelectedCounty}
            setCountyStoryDisplay={setCountyStoryDisplay}
            countyStoryDisplay={countyStoryDisplay}
            setShuffledIndex={setShuffledIndex}
            setImpact={setImpact}
            setNavCountySelect={setNavCountySelect}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick thing you could try is to change to this:

```
setMinZoom={minZoom}
setMaxZoom={maxZoom}
```

Since now are you just passing the function rather than the number?

I am currently working with react leaflet maps, are you using the [react-leaftlet package?](https://react-leaflet.js.org/)
Since it does not have a `Map`component. Could you share the imports?

Would also recommend not using state for constants since you can pass those directly to the component if you do not intend to change them.